# How to pull from current branch using ssh

Tags: git, ssh, git-pull, bitbucket-server

I am trying to pull from a specific branch on the command line using `SSH` like this:

```
git checkout hotfix/DEFECTS-001
git pull ssh://git@stash.****.net:7999/project/project.git
```

What this does is do pull from the "master" branch of the repo, but instead I want to pull from the branch I am currently on called "`DEFECTS-001`" using ssh. As far as I can tell I can't specify a branch with an SSH URL. As you can tell from the ssh URL I am using stash

Using "`git pull origin hotfix/DEFECTS-001`" does achieve this but it uses HTTP instead of SSH

How do I achieve that?

Comment: It isn't good way If you want to pull from specific branch. Use git pull origin name_branch

Comment: true, it does pull from the branch that I am already on, I've updated the question to reflect your comment, it's more clear what I am trying to do

Comment: I don't know what do you want to do. if you want to clone repository as first time. call git clone ssh://git@stash.****.net:7999/project/project.git if you want to pull use git pull origin name_branch

Comment: I want to pull using ssh, saying "git pull origin name_branch" pulls via http

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. You have to add your remote as origin and next call  git pull origin name_branch

Comment: Did you clone repository?

Comment: Yes my repository is cloned. I want to pull to my repo using SSH to avoid inputting a password as part of an automation script

Comment: and when did you clone your repository branch was already created?

Comment: if yes call git checkout origin/name_branch -b name_branch

Comment: Yes, when I cloned the repo the branch had previously been created.

Comment: if not call just git pull

Comment: so try git checkout origin/name_branch -b name_branch

Comment: Git pull does pull to my repo, however pulls via HTTP, I want to pull via SSH

Comment: ok so you have to add new origin repository

Comment: git remote add originSSH ssh://git@stash.****.net:7999/project/project.git

Comment: And than git pull originSSH

Comment: or git pull originSSH name_branch

Comment: Does this solution works?

Comment: Thank you to and remember use your expenses to help people :) Good luck

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you have to add ssh://git@stash.****.net:7999/project/project.git as your remote origin:

```
git remote add originSSH ssh://git@stash.****.net:7999/project/project.git
```

And next call

```
git pull originSSH name_branch
```

And then you can checkout on your branch

```
git checkout originSSH/name_branch -b name_branch
```

Comment: Could you add the part about the branch ie git pull originSSH name_branch